# How to sum all values of small pixels that overlap or exist within bigger pixels?

Tags: r, raster, terra

Given these two rasters:

```
library(raster)
rr1 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
rr1[] <- runif(ncell(rr1))
rr1[1]=2
rr1[10]=2
rr1[50]=2

rr2 <- raster(ncol=250, nrow=360)
rr2[] <- runif(ncell(rr2))
```

The pixels in the first raster rr1 are bigger than in the second rr2.

What I need is to sum all values of the small pixels in rr2 that overlap (or exist within) the pixels of rr1 that =2

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `terra::resample(rr2, rr1, sum)`. This will produce an output that is fully aligned with `rr1` (extent, resolution) and it will sum (weighted in case the overlap is not complete) the values of `rr2` to the new pixels. There are also other options than summing, you can refer to the help pages for possible functions.

Answer (score 1):

Example data

```
library(terra)
r1 <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, vals=1)
r1[c(1,10,50)] <- 2

set.seed(1)
r2 <- rast(ncol=250, nrow=360)
r2 <- init(r2, runif)
```

Solution. First use `resample` and then `mask`

```
x <- resample(r2, r1, "sum")
x <- mask(x, r1, maskvalue=2, inverse=TRUE)

as.data.frame(x)
#      lyr.1
#1  425.0315
#10 449.8206
#50 453.1009
```